# Ransack, connect multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

**Controller code:** Albeit wrong...

```
def index
  @q = Borrow.ransack(params[:q])
  @borrows = @q.result.includes(:request => :signup, :inventory => :signup)
end
```

Basically, a Borrow:

- Is a child of a `Request`, which is then a child of a `Signup`
- Is on a many-to-many relationship with `Inventories`, which are also children of `Signup`

In my Ransack search table, I need to search on both of these sets of associations. Yet the first works well:

*Working code:*

```
<div class="form group">
  <%= f.label :request_signup_email_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :request_signup_email_cont %>
</div>

<th><%= sort_link(@q, 'requests.signups.email', "Borrower Email") %></th>
```

But the second does not:

*Not-working code*

```
<div class="form group">
  <%= f.label :inventory_signup_email_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :inventory_signup_email_cont %>
</div>

<th><%= sort_link(@q, 'inventories.signups.email', "Lender Email") %></th>
```

Error: `undefined method`inventory_signup_email_eq' for Ransack::Search>:Ransack::Search`

Additional context on stuff I tried:

- Borrow and Inventory are in a many-to-many relationship via a join table called Invenborrow. So I tried one variation where I did `:invenborrow => :inventory => :signup`, but this threw an error that the `=>` was unexpected, which made me think that maybe triple links weren't possible...
- So then I tried just doing `:invenborrow => :inventory` because if I can get the `inventory`, I can run a search and find the signup. But that threw the same undefined method above...
- So now I think either my controller code is wrong, or Ransack can't do two different "trees" of associations.